# Visual Studio 2010 keeps crashing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a serious problem with our VS2010 with SP1. It is all the time crashing. I open it and 10 secs later I get crash and restart.

When I check the event viewer. I see that error log below:

I have tried everything

- deleting .suo and .user files
- clearing my tmp folders
- resetting user settings
- restructuring the project.
- I tried the open even a new project.

We use also TFS and all users are affected. noone is able to use VS. thats why i believe it is not VS related that I should re-install, It sounds like something with project but what? i dont understand.

Only difference between last working version and not working version is "a new class added", "a dataset was extended". nothing else!!

EVENT VIEWER LOG:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319

Exception code: 0x8004753b

Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc

Faulting process id: 0xad0

Faulting application start time: 0x01ccaf8b820071c5

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll

Report Id: e3138c45-1b7e-11e1-bb8c-001999505d92
```

**EDIT**

I have just found that code below causes VS to crash and restart. It is a simple linq code and I don't know why it should cause VS to crash. I am 100% sure it is the reason because when I take it off, everything is fine but when I include it. it crashes. cachedata is shared class having partners as Entity Framework code first object. any idea why? 
I have also other EF POCO objects in myCache data class which I call similarly in different classes but they work fine. So I tried to copy same code in that crashing class which works in other class, VS crashed again. likewise code below works in other class. what is up with this class? I have linq namespaces imported!!

thanks

```
Dim myPartner = (From item In myCachedata.partners Where item.partner_ID= partner_ID).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Very strange exception code.  Clearly environmental, start killing off processes with Taskmgr.exe, starting with anti-malware.

Comment: When exactly does it crash? When you open the IDE, you load your project, when try to only compile your project, or when you try to run it?

Comment: It was crashing 5-10secs after solution is loaded completely but I could manage the find the mistake which was a code mistake. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the error and it is really unbelievable error!! Actually I have had that code in other function written like below

Dim myPartner = (From item In myCachedata.partners Where **partner_ID= partner_ID**).FirstOrDefault()

see the where condition. I was trying to match parameter with itself. so that partner_ID is byval parameter of the function I have and this causes VS IDE to be crashed. I dont know if same error exists in C# or not but yes VB has it. If anyone can try and return feedback whether this is my VS or general, I appreciate. thanks.

PS, for me this doesn't give any build error (even though I never had time to build completely while it was crashing right after 5-10 secs).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing .NET 4 and re-installing? (re: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vseditor/thread/06ff7046-a993-40f3-a72d-4d7dd4b35ed2)

From the sounds of it, if all users are affected, it may be that you've got a PC that's been built from a clone, and it had a bad install?

Either way, worth a shot...or at least follow the steps in the article, it may point you in the right direction.

Comment: those affected PCs were installed more than 1 year a go and it started only a few days a go after writing some codes and checking in TFS. so it looks like everyone got downloaded that latest version and now affected. Solution corruption can't be because each user has its own solution. I am googling some similar issues and some people claims because of bad code bu how come bad code cause entire IDE to be crashed?

Comment: I have just found the reason why my VS IDE is crashing. code below causes VS to crash and restart. it is a simple linq code and I don't know why it should cause VS to crash. I am 100%sure it is the reason because when I take it off, everything is fine but when i include it. it crashes. cachedata is shared class having partners as Entity Framework code first object. any idea why? 

thanks

Dim myPartner = (From item In myCachedata.partners Where item.partner_ID= partner_ID).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I don't understand why do I get -1 for that post? Is there any solution for that or is is a bad question? I don't think it is a bad question while it is interesting to encounter such problem!!