# NOP Commerce Plugin Crashes Entire System

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, nopcommerce, bsod

I'm working on a fairly customized version of NOPCommerce 3.10. I don't even know how this is possible, but I have cloned an existing NOP Commerce "discount requirement" plugin, changed all of the relevant pieces of code to reflect a new name, etc, and when I run NOP Commerce locally through the Visual Studio 2012 IDE and debugger, install and then attempt to use that discount requirement plugin, as soon as I select it from the discount requirement dropdown, my entire computer immediately crashes. Not the site. Not IIS. Not Visual Studio. The whole computer immediately just turns off. I've reproduced the same issue on 3 other developer workstations, so it's not something weird with my PC.

To make matters even more confusing, I published the site, including this plugin to our staging server, and not only does it not crash the server, or the site, but the plugin actually functions completely as expected without any perceivable issues.

EDIT: If I reboot in safe mode with networking, the issue goes away and the plugin works as expected. However, if I use selective boot, disabling all startup programs and all services except those that are required for networking and SQL server, the issue recurs. I'm not an IT guy, so I really don't know what's the difference between safe mode with networking and selective boot with all but networking services disabled, but clearly there is a significant difference as it pertains to this issue.

How is this even possible, and more importantly, what could be causing this and how do I go about finding and resolving the issue?

Edit 2: If I debug on any workstation that is not the same model as mine, it works fine. I believe I have narrowed the issue down to the Intel Integrated HD Graphics display device and/or driver. I've tried several different versions of the driver to no avail, so it seems like either the issue is with the device, or it is so obscure that it's never been identified or fixed by the manufacturer.

Comment: to understand your issue, we need to look at the plugin code

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. The plugin works perfectly when I am in safe mode, when I deploy to the server, or on other workstations that are not the same model as mine. My question is not "what's wrong with my code?" it's "how is it possible for a web page to crash a computer?".

Comment: When in normal mode your plugin causes drop in the system, the error is in the code.

Comment: Other NOP Commerce plugins that I didn't write cause the same thing to occur. And if it's an issue with the code, why do all of these plugins work fine on other machines, including the staging and production servers?

Comment: Which pieces of the code would you like to see? The crash occurs when I attemp to select the plugin from the discount requirements combo box, and prior to the plugin settings being displayed.

Comment: you can test your plugin by excluding all logic. so basically just an empty plugin without any logic. If you are still experiencing any issue that means your plugin's logic is fine but I agree with Dmitry that you should have some problem somewhere in your logic.

Comment: Just to give you an idea. Sometimes things happen unexpectedly. 5 years ago I had this crash happening and I found out that it was crazy line in my code. I mean it could be that some lines of code in your plugin doesnt work with your hardware or causes some memory failure.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331535/visual-studio-2010-keeps-crashing

Comment: Yeah I've had bad code and weird situations before, but not like this. If the code works on other systems, I'm not sure what I could possibly change to prevent the crash and keep it working on those systems. The plugin itself is very simple, and I've tried debugging it by commenting out all lines of code and bring them back bit by bit, but the crash occurs on internal code somewhere as soon as it tries to return the configuration view so I'm not sure what else to try.